# Open port for internal_address in Rancher/Kubernates (RKE)?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, rancher, rke

I have the following configuration to setup the cluster using [Rancher (RKE)](https://rancher.com/docs/rancher/v2.x/en/installation/ha/kubernetes-rke/).

rancher-config.yml

```
nodes:
  - address: 192.168.88.204
    internal_address: 172.16.22.12
    user: dockeruser
    role: [controlplane,worker,etcd]
  - address: 192.168.88.203
    internal_address: 172.16.32.37
    user: dockeruser
    role: [controlplane,worker,etcd]
  - address: 192.168.88.202
    internal_address: 172.16.42.73
    user: dockeruser
    role: [controlplane,worker,etcd]

services:
  etcd:
    snapshot: true
    creation: 6h
    retention: 24h
```

According [Rancher Networking](https://rancher.com/docs/rancher/v2.x/en/installation/requirements/), I already open the following port for all nodes(192.168.88.204, 192.168.88.203, 192.168.88.202) as firewall-services.

node-firewall.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<service>
    <port port="2376" protocol="tcp"/>
    <port port="2379" protocol="tcp"/>
    <port port="2380" protocol="tcp"/>
    <port port="8472" protocol="udp"/>
    <port port="9099" protocol="tcp"/>
    <port port="10250" protocol="tcp"/>
    <port port="443" protocol="tcp"/>
    <port port="6443" protocol="tcp"/>
    <port port="8472" protocol="udp"/>
    <port port="6443" protocol="tcp"/>
    <port port="10254" protocol="tcp"/>
    <port port="30000-32767" protocol="tcp"/>
</service>

-> commmend

firewall-offline-cmd --new-service-from-file=node-firewall.xml --name=node-firewall
firewall-cmd --reload
firewall-cmd --add-service node-firewall
```

My RKE is installed on 192.168.88.151. For RKE ->

```
rancher-firewall.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<service>
    <port port="80" protocol="tcp"/>
    <port port="433" protocol="tcp"/>
    <port port="22" protocol="tcp"/>
    <port port="2376" protocol="tcp"/>
    <port port="6443" protocol="tcp"/>
</service>
firewall-offline-cmd --new-service-from-file=rancher-firewall.xml --name=rancher-firewall
firewall-cmd --reload
firewall-cmd --add-service rancher-firewall
```

So, I run the following commend to up my `RKE`

```
rke up --config ./rancher-config.yml
```

log is

```
[root@localhost ~]# rke up --config ./rancher-config.yml
INFO[0000] Building Kubernetes cluster
INFO[0000] [dialer] Setup tunnel for host [192.168.88.204]
INFO[0000] [dialer] Setup tunnel for host [192.168.88.203]
INFO[0000] [dialer] Setup tunnel for host [192.168.88.202]
INFO[0001] [network] Deploying port listener containers
INFO[0001] [network] Port listener containers deployed successfully
INFO[0001] [network] Running etcd <-> etcd port checks
INFO[0001] [network] Successfully started [rke-port-checker] container on host [192.168.88.202]
INFO[0001] [network] Successfully started [rke-port-checker] container on host [192.168.88.204]
INFO[0001] [network] Successfully started [rke-port-checker] container on host [192.168.88.203]
FATA[0016] [network] Host [192.168.88.202] is not able to connect to the following ports: 
            [172.16.22.12:2379, 172.16.22.12:2380, 172.16.32.37:2379, 172.16.32.37:2380, 172.16.42.73:2380, 172.16.42.73:2379]. 
            Please check network policies and firewall rules
```

My question is how to open the port for the `internal_address` for all nodes in `kubernates` cluster?

Answer (score 1):

May be it is lack of my experience. I just share what I found.
`internal_address` is have to be ip-address of (Gateway) of `docker`. 
To know the ip-address of docker for each node (192.168.88.204, 192.168.88.203, 192.168.88.202).

Run the commend `docker network ls`. You might be get following network information.

```
NETWORK ID          NAME                DRIVER              SCOPE
aa13d08f2676        bridge              bridge              local
02eabe818790        host                host                local
1e5bb430d790        none                null                local
```

And run the commend `docker network inspect bridge` to get ip-addres of `bridge`.
you will get the following similer info.

```
[
    {
        "Name": "bridge",
        "Id": "aa13d08f2676e40df5a82521fccc4e402ef6b04f82bcd414cd065a1859b3799d",
        "Created": "2019-01-31T21:32:02.381082005-05:00",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.17.0.0/16",
                    "Gateway": "172.17.0.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        ....
        ...
        ..
        .

]
```

and configure `rancher-config.yml` as below and run `rke up --config ./rancher-config.yml` again

```
nodes:
  - address: 192.168.88.204
    internal_address: 172.17.0.1
    ...
...
..
..
```

Comment: Check my answer above.  Your assumptions are not correct

Answer (score 0):

That is incorrect.

> The internal_address provides the ability to have
>   nodes with multiple addresses set a specific address to use for
>   inter-host communication on a private network. If the internal_address
>   is not set, the address is used for inter-host communication.

Per https://rancher.com/docs/rke/v0.1.x/en/config-options/nodes/#internal-address

You likely have a firewall issue.

Check your active zones and what interfaces are in those zones.

```
firewall-cmd --get-active-zones
```