# Failed to verify healthcheck kubernetes + rancher

Tags: docker, kubernetes, rancher, rke

Does any body know about the following error? I already running `kube-apiserver` on host `192.168.88.245]`

```
Failed to bring up Control Plane: Failed to verify healthcheck: Failed to check https://localhost:6443/healthz for service [kube-apiserver] on host [192.168.88.245]:
```

RKE up commend `rke up --config ./rancher-cluser.yml`

Details logs

```
INFO[0256] [certificates] Successfully started [rke-bundle-cert] container on host [192.168.88.245]
INFO[0257] [certificates] successfully saved certificate bundle [/opt/rke/etcd-snapshots//pki.bundle.tar.gz] on host [192.168.88.245]
INFO[0259] [etcd] Successfully started [rke-log-linker] container on host [192.168.88.245]
INFO[0260] [remove/rke-log-linker] Successfully removed container on host [192.168.88.245]
INFO[0260] [etcd] Successfully started etcd plane..
INFO[0260] [controlplane] Building up Controller Plane..
INFO[0260] [remove/service-sidekick] Successfully removed container on host [192.168.88.249]
INFO[0260] [remove/service-sidekick] Successfully removed container on host [192.168.88.243]
INFO[0260] [healthcheck] Start Healthcheck on service [kube-apiserver] on host [192.168.88.249]
INFO[0260] [healthcheck] Start Healthcheck on service [kube-apiserver] on host [192.168.88.243]
INFO[0261] [controlplane] Successfully started [kube-apiserver] container on host [192.168.88.245]
INFO[0261] [healthcheck] Start Healthcheck on service [kube-apiserver] on host [192.168.88.245]
FATA[0471] [controlPlane] Failed to bring up Control Plane: Failed to verify healthcheck: Failed to check https://localhost:6443/healthz for service [kube-apiserver] on host [192.168.88.245]: Get https://localhost:6443/healthz: EOF, log: I0205 07:10:08.522166       1 plugins.go:161] Loaded 6 validating admission controller(s) successfully in the following order: LimitRanger,ServiceAccount,Priority,PersistentVolumeClaimResize,ValidatingAdmissionWebhook,ResourceQuota.
[root@localhost ~]# Failed to bring up Control Plane: Failed to verify healthcheck: Failed to check https://localhost:6443/healthz for service [kube-apiserver] on host [192.168.88.245]: Get https://localhost:6443/healthz: EOF, log: I0205 07:10:08.522166       1 plugins.go:161] Loaded 6 validating admission controller(s) successfully in the following order: LimitRanger,ServiceAccount,Priority,PersistentVolumeClaimResize,ValidatingAdmissionWebhook,ResourceQuota.
```

`kube-apiserver` info, which is running as docker container on host (192.168.88.245)

```
[
    {
        "Id": "bb669a98fd09df705c309038c1e81748a76e334aed821a60415fcea3732aba79",
        "Created": "2019-02-05T07:06:51.657829117Z",
        "Path": "/opt/rke-tools/entrypoint.sh",
        "Args": [
            "kube-apiserver",
            "--bind-address=0.0.0.0",
            "--tls-private-key-file=/etc/kubernetes/ssl/kube-apiserver-key.pem",
            "--etcd-keyfile=/etc/kubernetes/ssl/kube-node-key.pem",
            "--requestheader-extra-headers-prefix=X-Remote-Extra-",
            "--requestheader-username-headers=X-Remote-User",
            "--etcd-cafile=/etc/kubernetes/ssl/kube-ca.pem",
            "--requestheader-allowed-names=kube-apiserver-proxy-client",
            "--service-cluster-ip-range=10.43.0.0/16",
            "--enable-admission-plugins=NamespaceLifecycle,LimitRanger,ServiceAccount,DefaultStorageClass,DefaultTolerationSeconds,MutatingAdmissionWebhook,ValidatingAdmissionWebhook,ResourceQuota",
            "--kubelet-preferred-address-types=InternalIP,ExternalIP,Hostname",
            "--cloud-provider=",
            "--etcd-prefix=/registry",
            "--insecure-bind-address=127.0.0.1",
            "--storage-backend=etcd3",
            "--requestheader-client-ca-file=/etc/kubernetes/ssl/kube-apiserver-requestheader-ca.pem",
            "--etcd-certfile=/etc/kubernetes/ssl/kube-node.pem",
            "--proxy-client-cert-file=/etc/kubernetes/ssl/kube-apiserver-proxy-client.pem",
            "--tls-cipher-suites=TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305",
            "--secure-port=6443",
            "--allow-privileged=true",
            "--tls-cert-file=/etc/kubernetes/ssl/kube-apiserver.pem",
            "--kubelet-client-key=/etc/kubernetes/ssl/kube-apiserver-key.pem",
            "--service-account-key-file=/etc/kubernetes/ssl/kube-apiserver-key.pem",
            "--client-ca-file=/etc/kubernetes/ssl/kube-ca.pem",
            "--kubelet-client-certificate=/etc/kubernetes/ssl/kube-apiserver.pem",
            "--etcd-servers=https://172.17.0.1:2379,https://172.17.0.1:2379,https://172.17.0.1:2379",
            "--proxy-client-key-file=/etc/kubernetes/ssl/kube-apiserver-proxy-client-key.pem",
            "--authorization-mode=Node,RBAC",
            "--insecure-port=0",
            "--requestheader-group-headers=X-Remote-Group",
            "--service-node-port-range=30000-32767"
        ],
        "State": {
            "Status": "running",
            "Running": true,
            "Paused": false,
            "Restarting": false,
            "OOMKilled": false,
            "Dead": false,
            "Pid": 27063,
            "ExitCode": 0,
            "Error": "",
            "StartedAt": "2019-02-05T07:31:52.985537625Z",
            "FinishedAt": "2019-02-05T07:31:52.643734399Z"
        },
        "Image": "sha256:ad8f7f0613557e8f3cffce5b69859807590aa4f47e79ab72bc1fc5029952cb81",
        "ResolvConfPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/bb669a98fd09df705c309038c1e81748a76e334aed821a60415fcea3732aba79/resolv.conf",
        "HostnamePath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/bb669a98fd09df705c309038c1e81748a76e334aed821a60415fcea3732aba79/hostname",
        "HostsPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/bb669a98fd09df705c309038c1e81748a76e334aed821a60415fcea3732aba79/hosts",
        "LogPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/bb669a98fd09df705c309038c1e81748a76e334aed821a60415fcea3732aba79/bb669a98fd09df705c309038c1e81748a76e334aed821a60415fcea3732aba79-json.log",
        "Name": "/kube-apiserver",
        "RestartCount": 69,
        "Driver": "devicemapper",
        "MountLabel": "",
        "ProcessLabel": "",
        "AppArmorProfile": "",
        "ExecIDs": null,
        "HostConfig": {
            "Binds": [
                "/etc/kubernetes:/etc/kubernetes:z"
            ],
            "ContainerIDFile": "",
            "LogConfig": {
                "Type": "json-file",
                "Config": {}
            },
            "NetworkMode": "host",
            "PortBindings": {},
            "RestartPolicy": {
                "Name": "always",
                "MaximumRetryCount": 0
            },
            "AutoRemove": false,
            "VolumeDriver": "",
            "VolumesFrom": [
                "service-sidekick"
            ],
            "CapAdd": null,
            "CapDrop": null,
            "Dns": null,
            "DnsOptions": null,
            "DnsSearch": null,
            "ExtraHosts": null,
            "GroupAdd": null,
            "IpcMode": "",
            "Cgroup": "",
            "Links": null,
            "OomScoreAdj": 0,
            "PidMode": "",
            "Privileged": false,
            "PublishAllPorts": false,
            "ReadonlyRootfs": false,
            "SecurityOpt": null,
            "UTSMode": "",
            "UsernsMode": "",
            "ShmSize": 67108864,
            "Runtime": "runc",
            "ConsoleSize": [
                0,
                0
            ],
            "Isolation": "",
            "CpuShares": 0,
            "Memory": 0,
            "NanoCpus": 0,
            "CgroupParent": "",
            "BlkioWeight": 0,
            "BlkioWeightDevice": null,
            "BlkioDeviceReadBps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceWriteBps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceReadIOps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceWriteIOps": null,
            "CpuPeriod": 0,
            "CpuQuota": 0,
            "CpuRealtimePeriod": 0,
            "CpuRealtimeRuntime": 0,
            "CpusetCpus": "",
            "CpusetMems": "",
            "Devices": null,
            "DiskQuota": 0,
            "KernelMemory": 0,
            "MemoryReservation": 0,
            "MemorySwap": 0,
            "MemorySwappiness": -1,
            "OomKillDisable": false,
            "PidsLimit": 0,
            "Ulimits": null,
            "CpuCount": 0,
            "CpuPercent": 0,
            "IOMaximumIOps": 0,
            "IOMaximumBandwidth": 0
        },
        "GraphDriver": {
            "Name": "devicemapper",
            "Data": {
                "DeviceId": "61",
                "DeviceName": "docker-253:0-7207168-a1bf4a074e482562707a2f224a46dead5c480d2f5346e26398e131b9326ea9bc",
                "DeviceSize": "10737418240"
            }
        },
        "Mounts": [
            {
                "Type": "volume",
                "Name": "2bcf8575371aa24b7675208e53345f4f0876e87b9a39b379d80689a6fce55f6a",
                "Source": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/2bcf8575371aa24b7675208e53345f4f0876e87b9a39b379d80689a6fce55f6a/_data",
                "Destination": "/opt/rke-tools",
                "Driver": "local",
                "Mode": "",
                "RW": true,
                "Propagation": ""
            },
            {
                "Type": "bind",
                "Source": "/etc/kubernetes",
                "Destination": "/etc/kubernetes",
                "Mode": "z",
                "RW": true,
                "Propagation": "rprivate"
            }
        ],
        "Config": {
            "Hostname": "localhost.localdomain",
            "Domainname": "",
            "User": "",
            "AttachStdin": false,
            "AttachStdout": false,
            "AttachStderr": false,
            "Tty": false,
            "OpenStdin": false,
            "StdinOnce": false,
            "Env": [
                "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
            ],
            "Cmd": null,
            "Image": "rancher/hyperkube:v1.11.6-rancher1",
            "Volumes": null,
            "WorkingDir": "",
            "Entrypoint": [
                "/opt/rke-tools/entrypoint.sh",
                "kube-apiserver",
                "--bind-address=0.0.0.0",
                "--tls-private-key-file=/etc/kubernetes/ssl/kube-apiserver-key.pem",
                "--etcd-keyfile=/etc/kubernetes/ssl/kube-node-key.pem",
                "--requestheader-extra-headers-prefix=X-Remote-Extra-",
                "--requestheader-username-headers=X-Remote-User",
                "--etcd-cafile=/etc/kubernetes/ssl/kube-ca.pem",
                "--requestheader-allowed-names=kube-apiserver-proxy-client",
                "--service-cluster-ip-range=10.43.0.0/16",
                "--enable-admission-plugins=NamespaceLifecycle,LimitRanger,ServiceAccount,DefaultStorageClass,DefaultTolerationSeconds,MutatingAdmissionWebhook,ValidatingAdmissionWebhook,ResourceQuota",
                "--kubelet-preferred-address-types=InternalIP,ExternalIP,Hostname",
                "--cloud-provider=",
                "--etcd-prefix=/registry",
                "--insecure-bind-address=127.0.0.1",
                "--storage-backend=etcd3",
                "--requestheader-client-ca-file=/etc/kubernetes/ssl/kube-apiserver-requestheader-ca.pem",
                "--etcd-certfile=/etc/kubernetes/ssl/kube-node.pem",
                "--proxy-client-cert-file=/etc/kubernetes/ssl/kube-apiserver-proxy-client.pem",
                "--tls-cipher-suites=TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305",
                "--secure-port=6443",
                "--allow-privileged=true",
                "--tls-cert-file=/etc/kubernetes/ssl/kube-apiserver.pem",
                "--kubelet-client-key=/etc/kubernetes/ssl/kube-apiserver-key.pem",
                "--service-account-key-file=/etc/kubernetes/ssl/kube-apiserver-key.pem",
                "--client-ca-file=/etc/kubernetes/ssl/kube-ca.pem",
                "--kubelet-client-certificate=/etc/kubernetes/ssl/kube-apiserver.pem",
                "--etcd-servers=https://172.17.0.1:2379,https://172.17.0.1:2379,https://172.17.0.1:2379",
                "--proxy-client-key-file=/etc/kubernetes/ssl/kube-apiserver-proxy-client-key.pem",
                "--authorization-mode=Node,RBAC",
                "--insecure-port=0",
                "--requestheader-group-headers=X-Remote-Group",
                "--service-node-port-range=30000-32767"
            ],
            "OnBuild": null,
            "Labels": {
                "io.rancher.rke.container.name": "kube-apiserver",
                "org.label-schema.build-date": "2018-12-20T16:43:39Z",
                "org.label-schema.schema-version": "1.0",
                "org.label-schema.vcs-ref": "1ed08cea7de947e05cc025a727a58973b5c45949",
                "org.label-schema.vcs-url": "https://github.com/rancher/hyperkube.git"
            }
        },
        "NetworkSettings": {
            "Bridge": "",
            "SandboxID": "1e0727d2b5e06ef1a1f4da0ad3fc91e619f8288d512adf41565d4e174a277105",
            "HairpinMode": false,
            "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
            "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "Ports": {},
            "SandboxKey": "/var/run/docker/netns/default",
            "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
            "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,
            "EndpointID": "",
            "Gateway": "",
            "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
            "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "IPAddress": "",
            "IPPrefixLen": 0,
            "IPv6Gateway": "",
            "MacAddress": "",
            "Networks": {
                "host": {
                    "IPAMConfig": null,
                    "Links": null,
                    "Aliases": null,
                    "NetworkID": "e7ef2fcec1a2befbc201a33a80bf3aaa8e6fcf125d104c648492351508ac94d8",
                    "EndpointID": "abb852ffe19b95b765410915d3fe4a9dd05bc3dd8b171396a455f0a07fc22d89",
                    "Gateway": "",
                    "IPAddress": "",
                    "IPPrefixLen": 0,
                    "IPv6Gateway": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                    "MacAddress": ""
                }
            }
        }
    }
]
```

**update**

rancher-cluster.yml

```
nodes:
  - address: 192.168.88.249
    internal_address: 172.17.0.1
    user: dockeruser
    role: [controlplane,worker,etcd]
  - address: 192.168.88.243
    internal_address: 172.17.0.1
    user: dockeruser
    role: [controlplane,worker,etcd]
  - address: 192.168.88.245
    internal_address: 172.17.0.1
    user: dockeruser
    role: [controlplane,worker,etcd]

services:
  etcd:
    snapshot: true
    creation: 6h
    retention: 24h
```

Comment: Can you share your cluster config?

Comment: @wrogrammer, I update cluster-config.

Comment: Did you realize that the internal_address is the same for all three nodes?  That can't be right.

What's your infrastructure look like?  Baremetal, Cloud provider?  Also can you sign onto the 192.168.88.245 node and grab the docker logs for the kube-apiserver.  That could help determine why it's not coming up.

Comment: Also make sure you're not running this as root as per, as there's an issue affecting RH and CentOS
https://rancher.com/docs/rancher/v2.x/en/installation/ha/rke-add-on/layer-4-lb/#6-configure-nodes

Comment: Also check your answer here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54472544/open-port-for-internal-address-in-rancher-kubernates-rke/54581935#54581935